# Error after deploy ASP.NET MVC 5 on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, deployment

i deploy my app on Azure serwer and after trying to get into my app i get:

**Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.**

So i added line in webconfig  to see error details and try to find help why it's not working. Could u help me?

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> ***Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.***
>
> **Description:** An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.ArgumentException: Format of the
>   initialization string does not conform to specification starting at
>   index 0.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 0.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
>   useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5705374
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +124
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) +59
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +27
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions) +167
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key) +61
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   +94    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__18(DbConnection
>   t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c) +12
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection
>   connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1
>   interceptionContext) +360
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings
>   appConfigConnection) +269
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +62
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection()
>   +12    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_Connection() +89
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type
>   contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config,
>   DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver) +367
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase) +252
>
>   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context) +96
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
>   +76    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action) +60
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   +357    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext
>   c) +7
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>   +110    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action) +198
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>   +73    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +28
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +15    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +38    System.Linq.Queryable.OrderByDescending(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 keySelector) +83
>   Kapitula.Controllers.HomeController.Index() +845
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3c()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.b__3e()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__19()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +545    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Are you pointing to an Azure Sql Database??...Did you try Continuos Delivery from a repo, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

Comment: Also check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203376/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-to-specification-startin

Comment: And this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119650/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specification-starting-a

Comment: i did not point to an azure Sql Database because i don't have it. i thought that if i publish my app with local database it will work. my connection string
`<add name="MyCS" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your connection string is set correctly.

Comment: @Hackerman I cannot comment yet. But my answer, while short, does point to the source of the issue.

Comment: my connection string `<add name="MyCS" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: seems like you are using local DB. guess you are missing the dababase file then. best will be use a remote database. e.g SQL Azure

Comment: so i have to create SQL Azure database and do what? :) because i have database created for my app using Code First method and Entity Framework